# Import module into vue.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I want to import the npm package vue-remove-attributes to remove my "data-testid" attributes from the DOM. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-remove-attributes

In the README they say i've to pass the module to vue-loader in my webpack config. I have webpack installed but my only config file is vue.config.js which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./",
  productionSourceMap: false,
  lintOnSave: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
}
```

I tried importing the module like this

```
const createAttributeRemover = require('vue-remove-attributes');

module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./",
  productionSourceMap: false,
  lintOnSave: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",

  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: new createAttributeRemover(),
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          use: {
            loader: "vue-loader",
            options: {
              compilerOptions: {
                modules: [createAttributeRemover("data-testid")]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
};
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how I can import the npm package in my vue config?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tag `vue-cli`, but you're using the `configureWebpack` property so it's my assumption that you are. You need to modify the existing loader rule. You can tap into it with chaining and add your options:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          // modify the options...
          options.compilerOptions.modules = [createAttributeRemove('data-testid')]
          return options
        })
```